# Ruby: Limiting a UTF-8 string by byte-length

Tags: ruby, string, utf-8, byte, rabbitmq

[This RabbitMQ page](http://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/amqp-concepts.html) states:

> Queue names may be up to 255 bytes of UTF-8 characters.

In ruby (1.9.3), how would I truncate a UTF-8 string by byte-count without breaking in the middle of a character? The resulting string should be the longest possible valid UTF-8 string that fits in the byte limit.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

For Rails >= 3.0 you have ActiveSupport::Multibyte::Chars limit method.

From API docs:

```
- (Object) limit(limit)
```

Limit the byte size of the string to a number of bytes without breaking characters. Usable when the storage for a string is limited for some reason.

Example:

```
'こんにちは'.mb_chars.limit(7).to_s # => "こん"
```

Comment: Nice, this seems like the best solution if you're using ActiveSupport >= 3.0. You will still need to use `mb_chars.compose.limit` if you have decomposed characters (see my answer).

Comment: Update: this now works on decomposed accented chars without removing the accent.

Answer (score 10):

`bytesize` will give you the length of the string in bytes while (as long as the string's encoding is set properly) operations such as slice won't mangle the string.

A simple process would be to just iterate through the string

```
s.each_char.each_with_object('') do|char, result| 
  if result.bytesize + char.bytesize > 255
    break result
  else
    result << char
  end
end
```

If you were being crafty you'd copy the first 63 characters directly since any unicode character is at most 4 bytes in utf-8.

Note that this is still not perfect. For example, imagine that the last 4 bytes of your string are the characters 'e' and combining acute accent. Slicing the last 2 bytes produces a string that is still utf8 but in terms of what the user sees would change the output from 'é' to 'e', which could change the meaning of the text. This is probably not a huge deal when you're just naming RabbitMQ queues but could be important in other circumstances. For example, in French a newsletter headline reading 'Un policier tué' means 'A policeman was killed' whereas 'Un policier tue' means 'A policeman kills'.

Comment: +1 just for the policeman example :). Google-translate confirms it. The pronunciations sound different enough though.

Comment: Just so everyone knows, the "combined character" issue only happens with [decomposed characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precomposed_character). No problem if the e-acute, etc is a single char.

Comment: You could avoid it by converting to canonical form C first

Comment: Thanks for this!  There's a slightly faster way than building the string linearly though, [I posted i as a separate answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67825008/2063546)

Answer (score 5):

I think I found something that works.

```
def limit_bytesize(str, size)
  str.encoding.name == 'UTF-8' or raise ArgumentError, "str must have UTF-8 encoding"

  # Change to canonical unicode form (compose any decomposed characters).
  # Works only if you're using active_support
  str = str.mb_chars.compose.to_s if str.respond_to?(:mb_chars)

  # Start with a string of the correct byte size, but
  # with a possibly incomplete char at the end.
  new_str = str.byteslice(0, size)

  # We need to force_encoding from utf-8 to utf-8 so ruby will re-validate
  # (idea from halfelf).
  until new_str[-1].force_encoding('utf-8').valid_encoding?
    # remove the invalid char
    new_str = new_str.slice(0..-2)
  end
  new_str
end
```

Usage:

```
>> limit_bytesize("abc\u2014d", 4)
=> "abc"
>> limit_bytesize("abc\u2014d", 5)
=> "abc"
>> limit_bytesize("abc\u2014d", 6)
=> "abc—"
>> limit_bytesize("abc\u2014d", 7)
=> "abc—d"
```

**Update...**

Decomposed behavior without active_support:

```
>> limit_bytesize("abc\u0065\u0301d", 4)
=> "abce"
>> limit_bytesize("abc\u0065\u0301d", 5)
=> "abce"
>> limit_bytesize("abc\u0065\u0301d", 6)
=> "abcé"
>> limit_bytesize("abc\u0065\u0301d", 7)
=> "abcéd"
```

Decomposed behavior with active_support:

```
>> limit_bytesize("abc\u0065\u0301d", 4)
=> "abc"
>> limit_bytesize("abc\u0065\u0301d", 5)
=> "abcé"
>> limit_bytesize("abc\u0065\u0301d", 6)
=> "abcéd"
```

Answer (score 5):

Rails 6 will provide a [String#truncate_bytes](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/4940cc49ddb361d584d51bc3eb4675ff8ece4a2b) that behaves like `truncate`, but takes a byte count instead of a character count.  And, of course, it returns a valid string (it does not cut blindly in the middle of a multibyte char).

Taken from the doc:

```
>> "".size
=> 20
>> "".bytesize
=> 80
>> "".truncate_bytes(20)
=> "…"
```

Comment: +1 That code is pretty smart - it even properly handles decomposed characters by using `scan(/\X/)` to split into grapheme clusters.

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
s = "δogδogδogδogδogδogδogδogδogδogδogδogδogδogδogδogδogδogδogδogδogδogδogδogδogδogδogδogδogδogδogδogδogδogδogδogδogδogδogδogδogδogδogδogδogδogδogδogδogδogδogδogδogδogδogδogδogδogδogδogδogδogδogδogδogδogδogδogδogδog"
count = 0
while true
  more_truncate = "a" + (255-count).to_s
  s2 = s.unpack(more_truncate)[0]
  s2.force_encoding 'utf-8'

  if s2[-1].valid_encoding?
    break
  else
    count += 1
  end
end

s2.force_encoding 'utf-8'
puts s2
```

Comment: It works, but what if the string is huge? It could be very inefficient to keep removing one utf-8 char at a time.

Comment: @Kelvin Answer has been edited. It should be much better now. Since the utf-8 char will be no longer than 6 bytes, the loop will end soon enough.

Comment: Seems incomplete - `s` hasn't changed. Do you need to pack `s2` to get the new string? Remember that the output also has to be utf-8.

Comment: @Kelvin Sorry... I forgot the output should be s2.

Comment: `s2[0]` seems to be the result, but it's in `ascii-8bit` encoding. If I call `.encode('utf-8')` I get `Encoding::UndefinedConversionError`.

Comment: That's really annoying... I've edited that again. After a `force_encoding`, you are able to test it by `encode('utf-8')` or `valid_encoding?`. btw, Believe me, I've experienced char encoding nightmares too since my native language is a complicated one.

Comment: `s2` is an array. You need to grab the result via `s2[0]`. Also, it can still break the last char. Add this after the first line and you'll see what I mean: `s.slice!(190,2)`.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16978/discussion-between-halfelf-and-kelvin)

Answer (score 1):

I tried Rails's `String#truncate_bytes` on my end but found it extremely slow on big random strings due to it's iterative implementation. So I tried doing something faster by first breaking the string quickly and then trying to remove extra bytes at the end which are incomplete unicode. Turns out in my testing `.chop!` is doing this fine, even when there are multiple bytes to remove. There's probably some edge cases I missed here but you can try this implementation. Also if you do find edge cases please let me know :)

```rb
# body is a ~2MB random bytes string
# > Benchmark.ms { 100.times { body.truncate_bytes(500_000) } }
# => 13339.49963748455
# > Benchmark.ms { 100.times { str = body.byteslice(0...500_000); str.valid_encoding?; str.chop! } }
# => 167.4932986497879

def self.smart_truncate string, max_bytes: 10
  truncated = string.byteslice(0...max_bytes)
  truncated.chop! if !truncated.valid_encoding?
  return truncated
end
```

```rb
expect(Result.smart_truncate("����������")).to eq("���")
expect(Result.smart_truncate("���AB")).to eq("���A")
expect(Result.smart_truncate("")).to eq("")
```

Comment: Nice idea. You might be able to make it even faster if you assume that the input string is already valid. Instead of checking `valid_encoding?` on the whole string, only check the final character: `truncated[-1,1].valid_encoding?` (Don't use `last` - it's slow). Example: `(0x10FFFF.chr * 10_000_000).then {|bigutf8| trunc=bigutf8.byteslice(0..-2); Benchmark.ms { p trunc[-1,1].tap{|s| p s }.valid_encoding? } }`. If you omit the `[-1,1]`, it will be be orders of magnitude slower.

Comment: Indeed, I thought about this but was under the impression that this could lead to false positives. If for example the last bytes of a multi-byte unicode codepoint was considered valid as a single byte (ASCII 7bit basically). But maybe this is not possible? I can't really find a definitive answer.

Comment: I had the same thought, but if you look at the [UTF-8 specification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Encoding), the first byte of a character can never be mistaken for a "continuation" byte; the latter always starts with bits `10` while the former never does. But if you're using this in production, it's probably good to write an exhaustive test to ensure ruby behaves correctly.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this ! looks like it works indeed. I didn't write extensive testing though so future reader beware :)

Answer (score 0):

#### Without Rails

[Fredrick Cheung's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12536491/2063546) is an excellent `O(n)` starting point that inspired this `O(log n)` solution:

```rb
def limit_bytesize(str, max_bytesize)
  return str unless str.bytesize > max_bytesize

  # find the minimum index that exceeds the bytesize, then subtract 1
  just_over = (0...str.size).bsearch { |l| str[0..l].bytesize > max_bytesize }
  str[0..(just_over - 1)]
end
```

I believe this also achieves the automatic `max_bytesize / 4` speedup mentioned in that answer, since `bsearch` starts in the middle.

Answer (score 0):

Ruby's String#byteslice can be used with a range. I'd recommend trying the following:

`string.bytslice(0...max_bytesize)`

The three dots will allow the max_bytesize value to be inclusive.

Comment: I was hopeful this would work, but unfortunately it may split a unicode character, leading to an invalid string: `"abc\u2014d".byteslice(0, 5).valid_encoding? # => false`